# SQL Group by specific time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello, I need best solution to group data by specific time periods. I need to group month data from 07:00:00 till 18:59:59 and then from 19:00:00 till next days 06:59:59. In database there is a lot of data so speed-wise effective solution would be preferred.

Also would be great to insert Shift letter in query. There is 4 shifts: A,B,C,D and i have calendar table.

```
Table [Shiftcalendar]:
[ShiftDate] | [SHIFT] | [Nextshift]
2013-11-11  |    N    |     A=B
2013-11-11  |    D    |     C=A
2013-11-10  |    N    |     D=C
....        |   ....  |    ....
```

Column [Shift] represents day or night, column [Nextshift] represents shift and next shift. N means night time and is from 19:00:00 till next days 06:59:59, D means day and is from 07:00:00 till 18:59:59.

```
Table [wrkSpeedInfo]:
[wrkActionDate]     | [wrkSpeed] | [wrkGlueValue] | [x1]
2013-11-11 07:00:35 |     200    |       300      |  20
2013-11-11 07:00:55 |     97     |       255      |  13
2013-11-11 07:01:23 |     127    |       124      |  15
....                |     ....   |       ....     | ....
```

I need to SUM [wrkSpeed], [wrkGlueValue] and [x1].

Someones help would be really appreciated :)

PS.: Don't mind my English writing skills, I am still on verge of improving it.

EDIT:
So long I doing lot of querys to take specific dates and shifts data, but would like to have all data in one query.

```
WHERE [wrkActionDate] BETWEEN '2013-10-03 07:00:00' AND '2013-10-03 18:59:59'
```

I can post full query but it takes lot of space and when would need to explain much more what i trying to do.

EDIT: 
Ok someone said to post full query:

```
SELECT [wrkActionDate]
  ,[wrkCntrId]
  ,DATEDIFF(second, (SELECT TOP 1 t2.[wrkActionDate] FROM [DW].[dbo].[wrkSpeedInfo] as t2 WHERE [wrkCntrId] = 'S1' AND t2.[wrkActionDate] < t1.[wrkActionDate]  ORDER BY t2.[wrkActionDate] DESC), [wrkActionDate])/60.0 AS MinPassed
  ,SUM([wrkSpeed])*DATEDIFF(second, (SELECT TOP 1 t2.[wrkActionDate] FROM [DW].[dbo].[wrkSpeedInfo] as t2 WHERE [wrkCntrId] = 'S1' AND t2.[wrkActionDate] < t1.[wrkActionDate]  ORDER BY t2.[wrkActionDate] DESC), [wrkActionDate])/60.0 AS SumWrkSpeed
  ,SUM([wrkGlueValue])*DATEDIFF(second, (SELECT TOP 1 t2.[wrkActionDate] FROM [DW].[dbo].[wrkSpeedInfo] as t2 WHERE [wrkCntrId] = 'S1' AND t2.[wrkActionDate] < t1.[wrkActionDate]  ORDER BY t2.[wrkActionDate] DESC), [wrkActionDate])/60.0 AS SumWrkGlueValue
  ,SUM([x1]) AS SumX1
FROM [DW].[dbo].[wrkSpeedInfo] as t1
WHERE [wrkActionDate] BETWEEN '2013-10-03 07:00:00' AND '2013-10-03 18:59:59' AND [wrkCntrId] = 'S1'
GROUP BY [wrkCntrId], [wrkActionDate]
```

So if I just could get all month data in one query that would be great, because now only getting data for one shift.

Would be great to get something like:

```
[ShiftDate] | [SHIFT] | [Nextshift] | SUM([wrkSpeed]) | SUM([wrkGlueValue]) | SUM([x1])
```

EDIT:
   They using MS SQL 2012. Can't change structure or anything, only can select data from DB.

Comment: I really tried... But just in vein :( Not yet good at SQL.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/  If you show some of your sql so far, that would be helpful.

Comment: People will close your question or downvote it if they see no effort.Edit you post with your attempt,no matter how lame it is.

Comment: Posting full query will explain more than you think. People post long questions - that is not a problem.  Also, please modify your tags. Is this MySQL or SQL Server? (Do not include both tags unless you are looking for a solution for both types.)

Comment: Ty for the tip. Still trying my best :)

Comment: I see Stack Overflow is a little bit out of my league yet. I guess ppl come here for more serious questions. Sry for interrupting your day guys.

Comment: Good post of code. Next step is to describe what about that query is not working.

Comment: Two things: 1) please don't use `BETWEEN` with variable-precision types (especially [timestamps on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)), and 2) could we get a bit more starting data and expected output, please (and any missing columns)?  We also need exact version of SQL Server.  Note that the current design of `NextShift` violates usual normalization practices (which are somewhat suspended in a reporting database, but I doubt that's the case here).

Comment: 1) Why? Just curious :)

Comment: @willCodeForBeer - mainly, because is it your intention to *exlude* from your reporting anything that happened at 06:59:59.437? It's usually far better with continuous data to use a semi-open interval - an *inclusive* start time and an *exclusive* end time - and you can't specify whether the endpoints are inclusive or exclusive with `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to sum all the values just based on the day you would simply have to 
`GROUP BY CAST(wrkActionDate AS DATE)`

But you don't want to group by the date precisely, you want to group based on your shift pattern. So to do that you can create a field that calculates which shift a particular time falls into, and then group based on that field.

```
SELECT [Shift]
    ,SUM(wrkSpeed) AS wrkSpeed
    ,SUM(wrkGlueValue) AS wrkGlueValue
    ,SUM(x1) AS x1
FROM(
    SELECT w.*,
        CASE WHEN (DATEPART(HOUR, wrkActionDate) >= 7 AND DATEPART(HOUR, wrkActionDate) < 19) 
                THEN LEFT(CAST(wrkActionDate AS DATE),10)+' D' 
                ELSE LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, wrkActionDate) AS DATE),10)+' N' 
           END AS [Shift]
    FROM [DW].[dbo].wrkSpeedInfo w
) w
GROUP BY [Shift]
```

Comment: Will try to do something like that.